# Gatsby graphql query works fine in development environment, but not onPostBuild

Tags: graphql, gatsby

**Problem occured afer updating to Gatbsy v3 and gatsby-plugin-sitemap v3** In my `gatsby-config.js`, I have configuration for sitemap:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
  options: getSitemapForLanguage('en'),
},
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
  options: getSitemapForLanguage('de'),
},
```

I got the the following function, which generates sitemap based on language passed:

```
const getSitemapForLanguage = lang => ({
  output: `/${lang === 'en' ? '' : lang}/sitemap.xml`,
  query: `
  {
    site {
        siteMetadata {
          siteUrl
        }
      }
    allMdx(
      filter: {frontmatter: {seo: {exclude_from_sitemap: {ne: true}}, languages: {in: "${lang}"}}}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            pathname
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`,

  serialize: ({ site, allMdx }) =>
    allMdx.edges.map(edge => ({
      url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${lang === 'en' ? '' : `/${lang}`}${
        edge.node.frontmatter.pathname
      }`,
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 0.7,
    })),
});
```

I created this using an in-browser IDE for graphql, that you get when you run `gatsby develop`. In that IDE I can see results and everything I need, but when I try to build it, I get:

`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'nodes' in undefined`
[Error of failed build process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jwoj.png)

For testing purposes I removed `, languages: {in: "${lang}"}` part in query, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it even work in `gatsby develop` since the plugin does only work in production mode. As you can see in the [`gatsby-plugin-sitemap` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/):

> *NOTE: This plugin only generates output when run in `production` mode!*
> *To test your sitemap, run: `gatsby build && gatsby serve`*

In `gatsby develop` is not even firing the plugin, even the query may work in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground.

In my opinion, the issue relies on the language parameter, you can't pass GraphQL variables like this in a Node file, like `gatsby-config.js` is. The approach is to create separate queries and serialize them somehow. Your configuration should look like this:

```
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    options: {
      query: `
        {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              siteUrl
            }
          }
 
         deSitemap: allMdx(
          filter: {frontmatter: {seo: {exclude_from_sitemap: {ne: true}}, languages: {in: "de"}}}
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
               pathname
              }
            }
          }
        }
         enSitemap: allMdx(
          filter: {frontmatter: {seo: {exclude_from_sitemap: {ne: true}}, languages: {in: "en"}}}
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
               pathname
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`,
      serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) => enSitemap.edges // here you will need to serialize both or append the language at the end
        .map(edge => {
          return {
            url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + path, // https://sitemaps.com/page-path
            changefreq: 'daily',
            priority: 0.7,
            links: [
              // https://sitemaps.com/page-path
              { lang: 'en', url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + path },
              // https://sitemaps.com/es/page-path
              { lang: 'de', url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}/de${path}` },
              // The default in case page for user's language is not localized.
              { lang: 'x-default', url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + path } 
            ]
          };
        })
      }
   }
```

*Source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4603*

Don't try to split it into a separate function, at least until you ensure that is working as expected.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. This used to work, before I bumped gatsby to v3 and sitemap plugin as well. Strange that it doesn't work anymore. Im aware, that sitemap is only created in production build, what I meant is that query itself works fine and returns results. I also tried to pass `languages: {in: "en"}` instead of variable, and it threw same error. But I will try your suggestions, thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, this is a piece of new relevant information. For that cases, since the `v3` implementation relies on the plugin, not in Gatsby until the plugin updates their dependencies and fixes the bugs, you may not be able to use it in the same way that you did... At least for a while...

Comment: Agree, I updated my original post with information about version upgrade, might be useful for someone who stumbles upon.

Comment: Yeah well clearly it doesn't like `filter` inside queries. Doesn't matter if you pass variable or static value, it fails with the same error. Error is only gone when you omit `filter`, I guess the only solution is to pull everything and then `filter` results on my own.

Comment: It's a good approach, at least for now. I guess that the loops that needs a callback may be buggy. Anyway, nicely debugged :)